# How to insert a particular record only once per day in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table named as `Attendance`, Here is the structure given below.

```
id     fname     lname    roll_no   date         time 
________________________________________________________
1      Qadir    Hussain   08cs18    19/04/2013   8:45am
2      Qadir    Hussain   08cs18    19/04/2013   8:50am
_______________________________________________________
```

i want to insert the record having `roll_no = 08cs18` only one time per day. not more than once per day.

I can restrict this via `if/else`. but is it possible to restrict this via sqlite query?

**Edit**

Acctually i m making an app of studnets attendance, I m using the QR_code to scan encoded roll_no. once a student scan its card for the first time it should insert the record (i.e id = 1) if user again scan it on the same day it should not insert. means a particular student should have a attendance record only one time per day.

Comment: put a unique key on `roll_no, date`?

Comment: Why does this have both the `sqlite` and `mysql` tags?  Which database are you using?

Comment: i have to this in both sqlite and in mysql also.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to insert programmatically once for day or you want to avoid to have more than one record of the kind described in the question. Also, it's not an Android related question.

Comment: I have edited the question. please have a look on it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both databases, make a unique key constraint on `roll_no` and `date`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX daily_roll_no ON Attendance (roll_no,date)
```

Then for mysql make your insert with the `IGNORE` clause. For sqlite, use `OR IGNORE`.

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO Attendance ....

 INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Attendance ....
```

mysql:

- [ignore clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html)
- [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

sqlite:

- [ignore clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)
- [create index](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single SQL:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO <tablename> 
      (<identifier>, <time inserted>, column1, column2, ...) 
SELECT <identifier>, <time inserted>, 
       COALESCE(column1,'new value 1'), 
       COALESCE(column2,'new value 2'), ...
  FROM <tablename>
 WHERE <identifier> = ...
   AND <time inserted> > <now minus one day>
```

The basic idea is: using `INSERT OR REPLACE` you can update an existing row or insert a new one depending on one or more conditions. In this case I update the row with the *same* values, if the row is not older than one day.

If the line is not existing or older than one day, you can assign new values using `COALESCE`.

I know this is only a kind of outline but may be it helps though .... Cheers!